# Classify version strategies into different labels as a new pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 84, 1: 84, 2: 84, 3: 84, 4: 124},'info_version': {0: '1.1.0',1: 'alpha', 2: '7.20345.98', 3: '2', 4: '${git.build.version}', 5: 'version not set'}})
```

The column info_version is full of values all different from each other, decimals, words,values in curly brackets, alphabets etc. All of these are various versions, and I want to sort them into labels.

Like all the single alphabets go into a label Names like this:

```
Names= ["develop", "draft", "genesis", "living", "main", "master", "next", "BETA", "DEV", "VERSION" , "ALL"]
```

And for all the values which start with, let's say 7, go into a label as this:

```
SemanticVer7 = ['7.0', '7.0.0','7.1.0', '7.1.1', '7.10.3', '7.10.4', '7.10.5', '7.18.0']
```

and this results in a new dataframe column as this:

| info_version | Version |
| --- | --- |
| 7.10.3 | SemanticVer7 |
| alpha | Names |

Till now I tried using `np.select` and `np.where`, but both of them can only take a maximum of 2-3 arguments, and my range is quite broad. I could only be successful if I take in one parameter like this code I wrote below (very basic at the moment) :

```
import numpy as np
def func(row):
    if row['info_version']== 'v1': return 'V1'
    elif row['info_version']=='1.1.0': return '1.1.0'
    elif row['info_version']=='0': return '0'
    elif row['info_version']=='7.8.1': return '7.8.1 '
    elif row['info_version']=='2': return 'Version 2'
    elif row['info_version']=='version not set': return 'Unversioned'
    elif row['info_version']=='2018-08-31': return 'Timestamps'
    elif row['info_version']=='2018-08-31T00:00:00Z': return 'Timestamps with code'
    else: return 'Undefined'

df.loc[:, 'Version']=df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

But this is far from what I want to achieve, as there are a lot of values to sort, I am bit lost on how to continue forward with this, any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made an additional df1 dataframe to check for values. In which the 'kkk' column is checked for a match and if the values match, it gets the values from the 'aaa' column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 84, 1: 84, 2: 84, 3: 84, 4: 124},
                   'info_version': {0: '1.1.0',1: 'alpha', 2: '7.20345.98', 3: '2', 4: '${git.build.version}',
                                    5: 'version not set'}})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'kkk':['v1', '1.1.0', '0', '7.8.1', '2', 'version not set', '2018-08-31', '2018-08-31T00:00:00Z'],
                    'aaa':['V1', '1.1.0', '0', '7.8.1', 'Version 2', 'Unversioned', 'Timestamps', 'Timestamps with code']})


def func(row):
    ind = df1[df1['kkk'].isin([row['info_version']])].index
    fff = df1.loc[ind, 'aaa']
    if len(fff) > 0:
        return fff.values[0]
    else:
        return 'Undefined'


df.loc[:, 'Version']=df.apply(func, axis=1)

print(df)
```

If you need something more. Namely, for example, to find out if there is a value from the 'Names' list in the df dataframe.

Created a dataframe with columns 'Names', 'SemanticVer7' which contain lists of these values. I've changed the values a bit to have more of a match. In the function in the name list generator, it is checked if the value exists, then the column name is written to the list.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Names':[['develop', 'draft', 'genesis', 'living', 'alpha', 'master', 'next', 'BETA', 'DEV', 'VERSION' , 'ALL']],
                    'SemanticVer7':[['7.0', '7.0.0','7.1.0', '7.1.1', '1.1.0', '7.10.4', '7.10.5', '7.18.0']
]})

arr = df1.columns

def func(row):
    name = [i for i in arr if np.isin(df1[i].values[0], row['info_version']).any()]
    if len(name) > 0:
        return name[0]
    else:
        return 'Undefined'


df.loc[:, 'Version1']=df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, just what I was looking for, second method worked like a charm!